# Merging tags Scope and Allowed-questions

Tags: discussion, scope, allowed-questions

I was looking at the Meta-tags and I think ***scope*** and ***allowed-questions*** are very similar and should be merged.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Anyone disagree?

Comment: @ManishEarth Nope, I think it's a fine idea.